# Postgresql, case, select in when

Tags: postgresql, select, case

**System**

```
PostgreSQL 11.5 (Ubuntu 11.5-0ubuntu0.19.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1) 8.3.0, 64-bit
```

**Case**

Does `select` work in `case` condition? I need return 1 state from 4 states in `case`. I try to explain.

Shop has eshop (`store_id = 7`) and stores (`store_id = 1 - 10`, others, but not `7`).

Eshop and every store have `available_count` - in stock.

[image]

Logic is:

When `available_count` > 1 where `store_id` = 7 (eshop) then `in stock`.

When `available_count` = 0 where `store_id` = 7 (eshop) and `available_count` > 1 where `store_id` != 7 (at least one value is greater than 1 for all stores, for eshop is 0) then `in stock on store`.

When `available_count` <= 1 where `store_id` = 7 (eshop) or `available_count` <= 1 where `store_id` != 7 (at least one value is 1, others are 0, but if all are 0, then `not in stock`) then `on request`.

When `count_availability` = 0 where `store_id` = 7 (eshop) and `count_availability` = 0 where `store_id` != 7 (all values are 0) then `not in stock`.

**I tried**

```
case
when (select ja.available_count where ja.store_id = '7') > 1 then 'IN STOCK'
when (select ja.available_count where ja.store_id = '7') = 0 and (select ja.available_count where ja.store_id != '7') > 1 then 'IN STOCK ON STORE'
when (select ja.available_count where ja.store_id = '7') <= 1 or (select ja.available_count where ja.store_id != '7') <= 1 then 'ON REQUEST'
when (select ja.available_count where ja.store_id = '7') = 0 and (select ja.available_count where ja.store_id != '7') = 0 then 'NOT IN STOCK'
end as "availability",
```

It returns more than one value for `availability`, just 'IN STOCK' or '[NULL]' and sometimes seems there is problem with right value.

Is betterr way to do that?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need one row per product. So GROUP BY needed. And the query will look like

   ```
   SELECT product_id, (expression for availability)
   FROM sourcetable
   GROUP BY product_id
   ```
2. You have 3 general variants for the amount - 0, 1 or >1 (if some record is absent we must assume its amount value is 0). For to formalize we will substract 1 and get the sign (it will compact the amount into 3 values of -1, 0 or +1). For `store_id != 7` we can get max value only and ignore all another. So source data can be prepared in CTE, and final query will be

   ```
   WITH cte AS ( SELECT product_id, 
                        SIGN(MAX(CASE WHEN store_id != 7 
                                      THEN available_count 
                                      ELSE 0 END) -1) stock,
                        SIGN(MAX(CASE WHEN store_id = 7 
                                 THEN available_count 
                                 ELSE 0 END) -1) eshop 
                 FROM sourcetable
                 GROUP BY product_id )
   SELECT product_id,
          CASE stock * 3 + eshop 
              WHEN -4 THEN ...
              WHEN -3 THEN ...
              ...
              WHEN 3 THEN ...
              WHEN 4 THEN ...
          END AS availability
   FROM cte
   ```

Test this. Fill the variants in final CASE by yourself, please...

Comment: Thanks, but I am using one cte already. Is possible use more ctes? I tried add new cte as cte2 under cte I have already, but it shows me syntax error near WITH.

Comment: @genderbee You can use as muct CTEs as you need. Separate them by commas: `WITH cte1 AS (...), cte2 AS (...), ..., cteN AS (...) {main query}`. Moreover, CTE (and main query) can refer to any previous CTEs as a data source in addition or instead of static table(s).

Comment: Yes, I did it now. But in case I have for first cte `with recursive`?

Comment: @genderbee If at least one of your CTEs is recursive you MUST use `WITH RECURSIVE`, if none CTE is recursive you may use either `WITH` or `WITH RECURSIVE`. Remember that if you use `WITH RECURSIVE` then you have additional overhead to each your CTE, ever it is not recursive. CTE recursivity is a property of separate CTE, it is not dependent by the presence and structure of another CTEs.

Comment: Thank you, seems it works. But I don't understand why is for example for `-2` value `IN STOCK`?

Comment: @genderbee `stock` in CTE can be: -1 (all stocks have amount=0), 0 (some stocks have 1, all another 0), +1 (at least one stack have 2 or more). The same for `eshop` (-1 means amount=0, 0 means amount=1, +1 means amount is over 1). They are combined into one value as `stock*3+eshop`. If this value is -2, then stock have value -1 and eshop is +1. This means "When available_count > 1 where store_id = 7 (eshop) then in stock." (i.e. `eshop=+1` means `available_count > 1`, and stock value doesn't matter).

Comment: I have one problem, seems that `group by` is not working in `cte2`. Not working in basic, I must solve this here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/247037/postresql-max-returns-all-rows-with-same-ids. Why `group by` is not working? And second question, is possible to add `when` from another table? For example `... WHEN 4 THEN 'SKLADEM' when delivery_time is not null then 'NA OBJEDNÁNÍ' else 'NENÍ SKLADEM' END AS ...`, it shows me `SQL Error [42883]`. Thanks.