# Postresql, max returns all rows with same ids

Tags: postgresql, max

**System**

```
PostgreSQL 11.5 (Ubuntu 11.5-1.pgdg19.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1) 8.3.0, 64-bit
```

**Issue**

Need return one `max` value from table for every `product_id` (1 product_id has 10 store_ids) based on `available_count`.

**Sql**

```
select
    product_id, store_id, max(available_count)
from
    j_product_store_availability
group by
    product_id,
    store_id,
    available_count
order by
    product_id,
    available_count desc,
    store_id
--limit 1
```

**Result**

```
product_id store_id available_count

130475  4   7
130475  1   4
130475  8   4
130475  2   3
130475  5   3
130475  7   3
130475  10  3
130475  3   2
130475  6   2
130475  9   0
130479  1   0
130479  2   0
130479  3   0
...
```

It returns rows for every `store_id`. Need to return just one max value based on `available_count`.

**Expected result**

```
130475  4   7
130479  1   0
(next product_id)
...
```

Thanks.

**Solution (Laurenz solution)**

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (product_id)
product_id,
store_id,
max(available_count)
from
j_product_store_availability
--where store_id = '7'
group by
product_id,
store_id,
available_count
ORDER by
product_id,
available_count desc;
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove `available_count` from GROUP BY and ORDER BY clause?

Comment: @McNets Yes, I tried. I tried `group by product_id` only, but it return `SQL Error [42803]`. Tried `OVER (PARTITION BY ...)`, but not working too.

Comment: Your added solution is a needless downgrade from the now correct answer of Laurenz. Don't use `max(available_count)` and don't add `GROUP BY`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using a non-standard PostgreSQL construct is no problem, the easiest way would be

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (product_id)
       product_id, store_id, available_count
FROM j_product_store_availability
ORDER BY product_id, available_count DESC, store_id;
```

Comment: Hi, still returns all rows for all `store_id`s. Needed just 1 row with `product_id` and `max(available_count)` from all stores `store_id`.

Comment: @All Why it is not working as in this example? https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/postgresql-max-function.php

Comment: Seems this is working. `SELECT DISTINCT ON (product_id) product_id, store_id, max(available_count)
FROM j_product_store_availability
group by product_id, store_id, available_count
ORDER BY product_id, available_count desc;`.

Comment: Sorry, I have fixed the answer.